# Dynamic div containing selected text inside another div

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` element. I will copy-paste some text in this `div`. Then, upon clicking a create button, another `div` will be created inside the `div` with the selected text inside it. The new `div` will have a different background-color, different fonts, and other style properties. But my code isn't working. Please help me to figure out the mistakes. Thanks!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>select</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function changeit(){
            var slctn = document.getSelection();
            var strings = slctn.toString();
            alert(strings);
            var get_id = document.getElementById("myspace");
            var elem = document.createChild("div");
            var design = document.createAttribute("style");
            design.value = "background-color:white;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;font-family:CURSIVE;";
            elem.setAttributeNode(design);
            elem.createTextNode(now);
            get_id.appendChild(elem);
            alert("it is done");
        }
    </script>
    <div contenteditable="true" width="400px" height="500px" style="background-color:pink;display:block;" id="myspace">ddd</div>
    <input type="button" value="select" onClick="changeit();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create `div` element you should use

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
```

instead of

```
var elem = document.createChild("div");
```

And `createTextNode` is performed over `document` something like

```
document.createTextNode('now');
```

Working [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7keR9/)

Comment: @user3138436 Have you seen the `DEMO` which is working?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function changeit(){
var slctn=document.getSelection();
var strings=slctn.toString();
alert(strings);
document.getElementById("myspace").appendChild('<div style="background-color:white;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;font-family:CURSIVE;">'+document.getElementById("myspace").innerHTML+'</div>');
}
</script>
```

Works?